# Ditto Clipboard Send to Friends Not Working

Tags: windows, networking, clipboard, ditto

I'm currently running Ditto Version 3.18.46.0 11-8-12 and Windows 8.1 on two computers.

Both of the computers are on the same network and have stack IP Addresses. I have tried both using Ip addresses and Computer Names, but can't seem to get Ditto to display the "friends" in the Send To List.

My settings are listed below:
[image]

Ditto doesn't show KT-TABLET in the Send-To Menu. I have tried using Ip addresses but it doesn't work either.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case you still haven't figured it out or for anyone else who stumbles onto this page with the same question - you need to add the computer to the list on the bottom. Just double click on any empty line. Computers in that list will show up in the Send to list.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for your answer.  I'm not familiar with this software so this may be a stupid question.  Will your instructions be obvious to any user, will it be readily apparent what you mean?  If someone might be confused, could you expand your answer to make it idiot-proof?

Comment: I am a new user and it was clear to me that he ment the list at the bottom. I thought that is just a log but you have to whitelist the computers you want to send clips to

Answer (score 1):

Now in 2021. **Disable Receiving Clips** comes checked by default. Just uncheck it. Adding the computer names and IPs in the friends' section is optional.

Regards,
Carlos